# Excel - count in range only if cell in the same row as the cell in range satisfies a condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

So, let's say I have a table like this one:

```
     A  |  B
=============
1 |  1  | 0.5
2 |  1  | 0.3
3 |  0  | 0.5
4 |  1  | 0.5
5 |  1  | 0.2
6 |  0  | 0.3
7 |  1  | 0.5
8 |  0  | 0.6
9 |  1  | 0.4
10|  1  | 0.8
```

This is a small example table, but keep in mind that my real table has a couple of thousand rows.

So, if I want to count the number of occurrences of 0.5 in column B, I would use a formula like this:

```
=COUNTIF(B:B;0.5)
```

... and the output would be 4 in this case. But how do I count the number of occurences of 0.5, but only if the corresponding cell in column A has a value of 1? In this case the output should be 3.

Comment: I would suggest using a pivot table, even though answers below are good and easy to fit.

Comment: Thanks everybody. All your answers helped me and I've accepted Martin's answer since he has the smallest reputation. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,0.5)
```

COUNTIFS will let you specify multiple criteria to count on.

Answer (score 4):

Either:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,1,B:B,0.5)
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A:A=1)*(B:B=0.5))
```

*COUNTIFS* can be used with versions of Excel 2007 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(A:A,"1",B:B,"0.5"))
```

Reference for COUNTIFS (used for multiple criteria):

- http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/excel-help/countifs-function-HA010047494.aspx
- http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/countifs.php